# How do you go back to an earlier node?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

```
while(element != null)
{
    //temp = element (useless)
    element = element.node;

    //can't do (element.node).method();
    //neither temp.method();
}
```

To traverse a LinkedList we do the above. However, what if I want to go back to an earlier node? Is that even possible? I thought about storing the node in a temp variable, but I wouldn't be able to changes the nodes in the LinkedList since the temporary variable would only store the value of the node and not the object.

I didn't expect LinkedList to be so difficult to work with, because I was used to working with non-dynamic data structures (array).

Comment: You will need to give us more context.  Can you give us the declaration of the class for `element`?

Comment: Do you need to write your own list?  If not, consider using Java Collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a related data-structure called a ["Doubly linked list"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list), in which in addition to storing a pointer to the next element, you ALSO store a pointer to the previous element. This way you can not only go down the list, but also back up. Will this serve your purpose?

Also, to respond to your suggestion of using a temporary variable, I think that will in fact work as long as the data you are storing is an object (instead of a primitive), and the changes you need to make are changes to the object rather than reassignment of the object.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I need to delete and add elements in the LinkedList. Also, I want to avoid using doubly linked lists.

Comment: If `element` is some node object and you assign a temporary variable to it using `Node temp = element;` (or something like that), then changes you make to the `temp` will also affect `element`.

Comment: The exception is if you were to reassign `temp` with something like `Node temp = element; temp = new Node();` In this case, `element` will NOT be the new node.

Comment: Ok, so if Node is a proper Node as in public class Node { private Car aCar; private Node node;} you could just put it in temp (save the reference) to manipulate the object the reference is referencing to? sorry i am very confused.

Comment: Yes. Assigning a `temp` to it will give you a reference which will allow you access to the actual node in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Doubly linked list, as Jimmy Lee mentions above, is the classic approach.  You could also save references to "interesting" nodes.  Or you could create a new linked list with the links going in the opposite direction as you traverse the list.  And finally, one trick is to simply reverse the links as you traverse the list, but this change the original list.

Comment: how do you save the references? like i have no idea. i wasn't taught such a method.

Comment: Everything in java is done by reference.  When you say in your example `element = element.node`, element now contains a reference to the thing that element.node referenced.  If you're coming from a C programming background, references are someone analogous to pointers.